# Discussion about grammar

Tags: discussion

I refer to this topic:

> [Is the sentence "Queueing is so thoughtful of you." grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409158/is-the-sentence-queueing-is-so-thoughtful-of-you-grammatically-correct/409826?noredirect=1#comment976747_409826)

I ask the person who downvoted my answer, why. I have a guess who may be, since some comments are self-explanatory.
For example see the answer "If it is a spelling error (which I'm inclined to agree)" says everything about the prejudice. When you don't want to concede something, you deny it.
In my opinion when there is an evident attack to a person, and not the answer he gives, well that spoils the whole experience of the exchange.
If the idea is bad, you can downvote it of course, better with a comment, and best if the comment is well argumented.
I hope that someone can give it here an objective look, and see it through with impartiality.

I am discouraged enough to go on here on this basis.
For that reason I think I will leave ESE to the people who rule it in this way,
and let the others enjoy it the way it is.

Comment: What makes you think it's an attack on you, the person? It could just be a disagreement with your answer.

Comment: When someone comments your posts saying that "queuing" is not an error but a non-standard way of writing, and then hits you, I tend to see it at least as a biased answer.

Comment: @ealy How would you prefer that he inform you that he thinks your answer is wrong in both application and content? In song form?

Comment: You're taking this too personally. Hang out here a while, try not to take things too literally, and chill. Everyone's a pedant here, there's always a response of 'Actually, ...' or 'Yes, but...', or 'X and X are entirely different because of the invisible apostrophe'. So just have fun with it, we're all trying to shove our 6th grade social studies teacher's nose in it. That guy was a jerk.

Comment: My reading of that comment is that "I'm inclined to **agree**" shows a bias in favor of your answer, not against it. If it said "I'm inclined to **disagree**" I would understand what you mean by prejudice, but as it is, I'm confused...

Answer (score 7):

You may be getting marked down for calling a spelling discrepancy a grammatical error. Sloppy spelling is no more a matter of grammar than sloppy penmanship is, and for the same reason.

You should avoid taking downvotes on your postings as personal attacks on you rather than judgements cast upon your answer. These are very different things.

Comment: I didn't see the question or answer being discussed here until my attention was directed to it by this Meta-question. I just downvoted the answer. I can confirm I did it because it implicitly asserts the spelling error creates grammatical problems, which is incorrect and a frustratingly prevalent misapprehension which I wish to prevent from spreading further.

Answer (score 4):

#### Just because he doesn't ever agree with you doesn't mean he has a problem with you personally

I'm sorry you got this impression and it's never something we want to give new users, but I see nothing in his words that leads me to believe he was out of line or insinuates it was a personal attack. He disagreed with your opinion that spelling is grammar, argued why he felt that way, and he kept it civil.

In regards to the [link you commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388543/are-spelling-punctuation-and-capitalization-part-of-grammar) on the answer, that post is a testament to how that topic has different views and no definite boundaries; it supports the idea that people have differing opinions on that topic. Honestly, it appears that most took the side of those items **NOT** being considered grammar. So, if anything, that link hurts your case.

All in all, we at ELU never want to discourage new or existing users, but we also will not coddle them. People on here have different opinions and sometimes that can be difficult. This is something that will be found anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion, but I would like to know why the downvoting if the answer reports an error in the advertisment. Which has to be disputed if considered grammar or not. Why say "If it is a spelling error (which I'm inclined to agree)" if you know that it certainly is an error. And what do you see in when he says "Queuing is certainly non-standard", when you know that it's not true. It's defending at all costs a personal position. We have at least to respect the truth, if something is an error, you don't call it a justifiable or non-standars way of writing.

Comment: Everything you claim is "the truth" is not necessarily factual. Try reading  [Queuing or Queuing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/queueing-or-queuing). It can be written either way, which is why assuming that it is a spelling error is not accurate, because it can be spelled both ways. His comment that it is "non-standard" is also not necessarily factual but also not necessarily wrong; it all depends on how one defines **standard**. He probably meant that is was not the original spelling.

Comment: As for the downvote, he most likely downvoted because he disagreed that your answer was beneficial to the original question. Once again, a downvote is a matter of opinion. If you don't agree with an answer, you can downvote it and you're not required to explain why, although I feel he did explain why.

Comment: @ealy: "non-standard" does not mean "not an error" or "justifiable". It's more like the opposite!